# Firebase get data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I need to get data from firebase where 'x' value equal to 'y'. I read all documentation, but I couldn't find anything helpful to do this. Any help will be appreciated

I need something like this

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE x = y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a reference, order by the child key, and then specify an `equalTo()` clause.

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("height").queryEqualToValue(25)
   .observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot) in
    print(snapshot.key)
})
```

[See the docs on querying for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I thought this just sorts rows by field