# Get initial collection values from Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

In my node app I try to get access to Firebase, which contains a few collections.

`var firebase = require('firebase');
 firebase.initializeApp({myConfig: "Here"});
 var database = firebase.database();
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref()`

How exactly do i get all rows of a particular collection or all collections in database? Printing those variables gives strange structured objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase get data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383160/firebase-get-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should totally be looking into [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data) to get this information.

The way you retrieve will depend on what exact behavior you are expecting. And the documentation is excential to understand how firebase behave as a database in wich one of the possible cases.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Snippet above will look into any change on your entire database (since you are not specifying any child like `ref().child("users")`) and log it as a javascript Object.

Good luck and, again, go to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#value_events). :)

Comment: maybe I had some connection issues on my vm - today all looks fine,you example with .on(), mine with .once(). 
Thank you very much, still. Will go RTFM :)